# How to use azure traffic management with a custom service url endpoint?

Tags: azure, failovercluster, azure-traffic-manager

I want to provide failover proof url for my service endpoint to users using traffic management. I have a service instance running at http://vm1.cloudapp.net/myservice:8888/index.html. If this instance goes down then the service auto starts on vm2 at http://vm2.cloudapp.net/myservice:8888/index.html n vice versa.
I want azure to hide the underlying service urls to user and expose the service at http://myservice.trafficmanager.net
Is this possible? If so, how ? From reading the documentation of traffic manager service, it looks like you can failover only at DNS level and not at url endpoint level

Comment: I'm confused by your question. When using traffic manager, you *would* use `myservice.trafficmanager.net`, not `vm1.cloudapp.net` or `vm2.cloudapp.net.` Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems like traffic manager configuration allows us to specify a custom port number and the service doesn't need to be hosted at port 80. So traffic manager works for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several parts to this.

Firstly, you are right that Traffic Manager works at the DNS level.  It doesn't see your HTTP traffic and hence doesn't see the full URL.  Since your two services instances have different DNS names, there's no issue here--you configure Traffic Manager with both names as separate 'endpoints', and Traffic Manager will direct traffic to those endpoints by providing one or other in each DNS response.

Secondly, you want to hide the URL paths.  Since Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, it doesn't see your HTTP traffic and hence doesn't see the URL, only the domain name.  Therefore this is something you have to handle at the application level (just as you would for a single-instance service that doesn't use Traffic Manager).

The only thing to be careful of is to make sure you configure the correct URL port and path in the Traffic Manager endpoint monitoring configuration.  Just make sure that Traffic Manager shows your endpoints as 'Online', and you're good.

Jonathan